# Multiplication of row values of matrix by values in other matrix based on identifier in other column

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

is there a way to do following multiplication of two matricies without a loop?
Matrix A contains numeric values in one column and currency identifiers in the other. Matix B contains the  currency identifiers and a respective exchange rates to the goal currency. Goal --> convert all values in matrix A to a new matrix containing all values in one currency.

```
A <- data.frame(Values, Currencies)
  Values Currencies
1   1000        EUR
2   1213        USD
3   5345        CHF
4   2323        EUR


B <- data.frame(CurrencyID, Spot)
  CurrencyID   Spot
1        EUR 1.0557
2        USD 0.9786
3        CHF 1.0000´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do a `join` with `data.table` `on` the 'Currencies/CurrencyID' column of both datasets and create the 'Converted' column by multiplying the 'Values' with the 'Spot'.  It creates the new column 'Converted' in the 'A' dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B, Converted := Values * Spot, on = .(Currencies = CurrencyID)]

A
#   Values Currencies Converted
#1:   1000        EUR  1055.700
#2:   1213        USD  1187.042
#3:   5345        CHF  5345.000
#4:   2323        EUR  2452.391
```

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(Values = c(1000L, 1213L, 5345L, 2323L), Currencies = c("EUR", 
"USD", "CHF", "EUR")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))

B <- structure(list(CurrencyID = c("EUR", "USD", "CHF"), Spot = c(1.0557, 
0.9786, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"
))
```